# Auto-update buttons in W8.1P App when Accent colour is changed

Tags: c#, windows-phone

I have an app with several buttons, with which I've set the background to match the phone's Accent Colour. I've noticed that if the user changes the Accent Colour with my app open in the background, then the buttons will retain the previous colour. The app has to be closed (Hold back button, swipe off screen) and opened again to update the buttons. Is there a way for  my app to automatically check the accent colour everytime the mainpage is shown?

Comment: If someone is downvoting my question, could you at least have the courtesy to let me know why? I can't improve unless I know where to improve upon.

Comment: Well, you commented Dante's answer saying you _can't find XAML part_ so you hardly understand something of what you are doing. I suggest to buy a good manual and start studying.

Comment: That would be because I haven't included a reference to an assembly. This is my first app, give me a break.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because Accent can only be changed outside your app, you may just change the colors for your MainPage when it is navigated to.

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
```

If you are not using `MainPage.Foreground`, you can take advantage of it, by binding to all the buttons you want, and only take one line to set it in the same function above.

```
// in MainPage.xaml.cs

protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    this.Foreground = App.Current.Resources["PhoneAccentBrush"] as Brush;
}
```

and

```
<!-- in MainPage.xaml -->

<Page
    ....    
    x:Name="Root">

    <Grid>
        <Button Foreground="{Binding Path=Foreground, ElementName=Root}"
                Content="..."/>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Comment: This looks good, but where do I put the Grid you have there? I've put in this.Foreground = App.Current.Resources["PhoneAccentBrush"] as Brush; but it can't seem to find Brush at the end. Is there a reference I'm not using?

Comment: @Anthony what did you mean by "can't seem to find"?

Comment: "The type or namespace "Brush" could not be found (are you missing a directive or assembly reference?)"

Comment: @Anthony add `using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;`. By the way, please accept the answer if it works.

Comment: Same error when I added that. Couldn't find the Xaml part. Not sure what I'm doing wrong here, this is my first app :S

Comment: @Anthony Please find the reference in [Channel 9](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Windows-Phone-8-Development-for-Absolute-Beginners/Part-4-Introduction-to-XAML) to learn about XAML.

Comment: I'm not really ok with this answer because the "PhoneAccentBrush" can be override for your app. The problem is that when you bind a Background or any brush property to "{StaticRessource PhoneAccentBrush}", the binding is not refreshed on changing the accent color because this is a static binding.
To solve this issue, you have to bind your control's property to a property of your ViewModel, which will manage the brush to return.